# Download PDF file from WebPage WatIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I have a website (Bank WebSite) i using WatIn to Login and getting to page with links(with pdf files), each link open a Page with opened pdf.file,on that page i have only the opened pdf file and button to download this file(no need to click on it because page automaticlly popUp message with save\saveAs)

I tried:

1- `string page=browser.body.OuterHtml`

Not working i cant see the Iframe,i cant find it too.

2-`int response = URLDownloadToFile(0, Link, FullFilePath, 0, 0);`

Not working a gettin login page it because  i need cookies

```
3-  WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);
```

Gives me the same result.

**I CAN'T GET COOKIES FROM WatIn Browser and SET IT IN WebClient**

```
CookieCollection cookies = _browser.GetCookiesForUrl(new Uri(url));
string cookies= ie.Eval("document.cookie");
```

returns my  only 1 parameter

sow please do not say to me that i  just need to get cokies from WatIn and set it in myWebClient.

Sow any ideas how can i save this pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using iTextSharp library, which would give a list helpful methods to download the PDF. Sample code is below...

```
Uri uri = new Uri("browser url");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(uri);
```